Why tab completion in PyCharm python console is much slower than a terminal?
I am running my python script in python console of PyCharm and the tab completion of a custom object attributes is pretty slow (unusable). However when I run the same code is a terminal using IPython the tab completion is fast. I tried increasing the memory limits of PyCharm with no avail. Is this a limitation of PyCharm that is not efficient in looking up attributes? Or some setting that needs to be corrected.

My take is that PyCharm is a full-blown IDE, so that it's slower than IPython. It's like running a AAA game vs running the Solitare game. PyCharm is an integrated development environment (IDE) used for programming in Python. It provides code analysis, a graphical debugger, an integrated unit tester, integration with version control systems, and supports web development with Django.
